# disabling mouse events react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am trying to disable mouse events in react. I tried `pointer-events: none` and `document.body.style.cursor = 'none'`. both didn't work. I tried it on whole body or on App. Can't get it to work. I basically wanted to hide mouse pointer for sometime and put it back.

Comment: hide the cursor? or disabled click events? or both?

Comment: @DacreDenny hide the cursor. basically i don;t want the user to interact with the website for interim.

Comment: @I'mLimit i tried exactly the same like in the other link you mentioned(in line style). it didn't work.

Comment: @user3900196 can you include the basics of your code to show what you've attempted - we can better help from there

Comment: @DacreDenny: i do use MediaRecorder to record the screen for some time.i have a state in react to maintain this when it happens. Then in App.js i use <div className="App" style={{ pointerEvents: ui.screenSharing ? 'none' : 'auto' }}></div>

Comment: can you include the code for your react component where you're trying to set the cursor styling?

Comment: What is `ui.screenSharing`?

Comment: ui.screenSharing is just a mobx property(boolean) which is set/unset based on user action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok you need to wrapper that object

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div style={{cursor: 'none'}}>
             <button style={{ pointerEvents: 'none'}}>
                Hello {this.props.name}
             </button>
           </div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World"/>,
  document.body
);
```

By base of CSS can't combine `pointerEvents: 'none',cursor: 'none'`
directly.

You need to wrapper that item and separate style like here

**DEMO:** https://jsfiddle.net/limitbrk/g9w7es5p/

> - CSS cant combine [How to combine cursor: not-allowed and pointer-events: none;](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46665625/11767915)
> - disable pointer-events [Can't disable pointer-events in React app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44211467/11767915)

Comment: i am trying to use this property on whole body of the html. for now I am just trying to use it in App.js when rendering. btw i tried to split no luck!

Comment: Let see the demo first

Comment: okay. seems to work. i have to individually get this for parent and child layers to get it to work. thanks!