# How to center div in middle of screen. Or, if using flexbox, how to disable outer div clickability but preserves inner div clickability?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, onclick

I have centered these 2 black buttons inside the grey div successfully with flexbox like [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bymrO.png)
`

```
#outerDiv{
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   width: 100%;
   background: #888; /* Only for demo purposes */
   opacity: 0.86;
  /* Styles for fixing always at bottom */
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0%;
}

#innerDiv{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

The problem is that I want the black buttons to be clickable but the outer grey div not. Grey div actually prevents me to click the page below (like the "ADD TO CART" white buttons showed in the image or anything under its hitbox).

I think the problem is caused because I set `width 100%; display: flex` so **I am wondering if there is a solution for centering the black buttons without setting a display: flex div without the div taking full width and preventing me to click** or **if I can disable the outer div clickability but preserving both the page under that div and the black buttons clickability.**

(I have already tried playing with minor `z-index` in innerDiv that in outerDiv)

Maybe is useful to let you know that I am using React, Scss and StyledComponents

Comment: Use `position:relative;` and `z-index:1;` on `#innerDiv`

Comment: @webomjaipur I've already tried that :c

Comment: Can you share online link or compiled HTML code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the CSS property `pointer-events` to `none` on the outer div,
and also set it to `auto` on the black button to do this.

- [A stackoverflow code example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44212571/10586489)
- [The MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)
- [An article about its usage](https://bitsofco.de/theres-no-reason-to-use-pointer-events-for-html-elements/)

Answer (score 1):

Check this post [How to disable clicking inside div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28083708/how-to-disable-clicking-inside-div)

Try by adding this to the outter div:

```
pointer-events: none
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the width: 100% on #outerdiv

Set #outerdiv { width: auto; margin: 0 auto; } to center it

Comment: it does not get centered. it appears on the far left, not in the middle

Comment: That's because you have position: fixed. In that case, you can set a fixed width to it, then left: calc(50% - (fixed-width/2))